# multiple pcap files to csv

Tags: python, tshark

I am trying to convert pcap files to csv for all files in a folder using python .My code does not give me any error neither the output.Actually I can do it with the tshark command line but I wanted to try it in python.Btw I am new to python

I am trying to convert pcap files to csv for all files in a folder using python .My code does not give me any error neither the output.Actually I can do it with the tshark command line but I wanted to try it in python.Btw I am new to python

Here's my code:

```
import os
import glob
file_path='path/to/pcap/files'
def create_csv(filename):
    x=f'tshark -r {filename} -Y sip -T fields -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e sip.From -e sip.to -E header=y -E separator=, > {filename}.csv '
    print(x)
    os.system(x)

for filename in glob.glob(file_path + '*.pcap'):
    create_csv(filename)
```

Comment: Hello Armageddon ! First of all, does your program print the tshark command ? if not, than it mean that you didn't get the pcap file in your `glob.glob(file_path + '*.pcap')`    

I tried with a **pcap** (and not a .pcapng) and its print me : "tshark: Some fields aren't valid: sip.to"    

I will look into tshark field and reach you back when I manage to fix the error

Comment: In order to check the output, you have to print the return value of the `os.system` call `print(os.system(x))`.

Comment: @RaiZy_Style yes it works completely fine if I do it for a single pcap file . I cam to know that in python for a single pcap file if your tshark command is right it will return the output as 0 which means you have successfully converted pcap to csv with req fields and if it returns any other number it means that it has created an empty csv file with no fields

Comment: @TheApache still the same output

Comment: @Armageddon That's strange when you say no output. Are you using the command line to execute this python file?

Comment: @Armageddon See my anwser and feel free to comment it if you have any issue.

Comment: @TheApache Nope I am using VSCode also I tried  this by changing  my cwd to to tshark 's dir still I get the same thing

Comment: Are you on windows or Linux ? 
If you open a cmd or a shell and you type "tshark" does it show the tshark output ? 
Or does it say something like "command not found" ?

Comment: @RaiZy_Style I use both and i have installed tshark in both

Comment: @RaiZy_Style the os.system works completely fine for a single file but i am not able to do it for multiple files i guess my code isnt right

Comment: @Armageddon If you open a cmd or a shell and you type "tshark -v" does it show the tshark output ? Or does it say something like "command not found" ?

Comment: @RaiZy_Style Yes it works It shows Tshark(Wireshark) 3.2.3 copy right Info running on Linux everything

Comment: @Armageddon Well, it work for me. With a single pcap, or multiple pcap.
Please see my anwser and try to provide more information on where it doesn't work so we can help you.

Comment: @RaiZy_Style Actually i am running this from vscode can this be a problem ?

Comment: @Armageddon Could be, try to use your script outside of vscode to give it a shot. Also, please see my anwser below.

Comment: @RaiZy_Style Yes sure Let me do that and if anything comes up i will let you know

Comment: @RaiZy_Style nope it didn't work

Comment: Please give more information on what doesn't work. With what you give, I can not help.

Comment: Actually I gave all the information to you . Even it doesnt give me any error so that i could point it out

Comment: @Armageddon Does the file you are looping to are printing in your for loop ? Are you sure your pcap is a pcap file ? Are you sure the path for the pcap file  is good ? Does it print you the tshark command ? Does the tskark command that is printed work in a shell ?

Comment: @RaiZy_Style yes my pcap file is a .pcap file everything is fine. Bro I got it I actually missed the / thats why it was not working

Comment: @Armageddon Does the file you are looping to are printing in your for loop ? Are you sure the path for the pcap file is good ? Does it print you the tshark command ? Does the tskark command that is printed work in a shell ?

Comment: Yes now it is printing

Comment: @Armageddon Does it print you the tshark command ? Does the tskark command that is printed work in a shell ?

Comment: the line should be glob.glob(file_path + '/*.pcap'

Comment: @RaiZy_Style yes it also shows tshark command

Comment: @Armageddon Does the tskark command that is printed work in a shell ? Can you copy past the tshark command printed and post it in a new shell (NOT VSCODE SHELL). Does the command work ?

Comment: @RaiZy_Style you can edit you answer and thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Armageddon You do realise that I already anwser this in my anwser under ?

Comment: @Armageddon Edit for what ?

Comment: @RaiZy_Style no need leave it

Comment: @Armageddon Ok, glad I can help. Feel free to mark my answer as the correct answer to this post so other people can see the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, make sure that the common issue under are valid for you.

### Common mistake :

1. Make sure that your pcap file is, indeed a pcap file. *Wireshark save by default in a **.pcapng** format.*
   `ls -alF path/to/pcap/files`
2. Make sure that your program are fetching those files. You can use a print like so :

```py
for filename in glob.glob(file_path + '*.pcap'):
    print(f"Current file is : {filename}")
    create_csv(filename)
```

3. Make sure `tshark` is installed (apt install tshark on linux)
4. You might need to provide the full path of tshark exe. Depending if you have tshark in your $PATH.

## Solution :

```py
import os
import glob
file_path='path/to/pcap/files/'
def create_csv(filename):
    # Typo in -e sip.to. Should be -e sip.To
    x=f'tshark -r {filename} -Y sip -T fields -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e sip.From -e sip.to -E header=y -E separator=, > {filename}.csv ' # Will not work 
    x=f'tshark -r {filename} -Y sip -T fields -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e sip.From -e sip.To -E header=y -E separator=, > {filename}.csv ' # Correct line
    print(x)
    os.system(x)

for filename in glob.glob(file_path + '*.pcap'):
    print(f"Current file is : {filename}")
    create_csv(filename)
```

## Check if the solution is working :

1. Does it print you every pcap file in the path given ?
2. Does it print you the tshark command ?
3. Can you copy past the tshark command printed and post it in a new shell (**NOT VSCODE SHELL**). Does the command work ?